# Dji Imports Generate Error in jUnit Tests Android

Tags: android, gradle, junit, dji-sdk

I'm trying to write junit tests for my Android application which uses the DJI Mobile SDK. The app compiles and runs fine, but when I import something like this to my testing file:

```
import dji.common.mission.waypoint.Waypoint;
```

I get the error:

```
error: package dji.common.mission.waypoint does not exist
```

I figure I should add these dependencies:

```
implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.7.1')
compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.7.1')
```

to my test module. Currently they are under dependencies in build.gradle (Module: app). How to I make them available to files in my test folder?

Comment: Did you try `androidTestImplementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.7.1'` and / or `testImplementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.7.1'`. And maybe also for the provided dependency.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found trying to write tests that touch the DJI SDK, you can't. It seems to me that this is an unfortunate side effect of their use of Secneo to encrypt their classes.  Even a simple junit test that references a simple class like:

```
@Test
public void testBatteryStateBuilder() {
    BatteryState batteryState = new BatteryState.Builder().build();

    assertThat(batteryState).isNotNull();
}
```

Won't even compile.

I think the only way to actually write tests for these is going to be abstracting any class I need from the DJI SDK and mocking it out so that the SDK isn't actually touched in a class. yay.